# How to create many folders in subfolder .......!

Tags: c#, winforms

How to create many folders in a sub-folder

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;
  namespace Progressbar
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string path = @"A:\DMS\SCOSTADL";
         try       
         {        
             // Determine whether the directory exists.
             if (Directory.Exists(path))             
             {  
                 MessageBox.Show("Paths Exists already!!!!!!!!!");
                 return;
                  }
             // Try to create the directory.
              DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
             MessageBox.Show("Directory Created Successfully....!");
             } 
        catch (Exception e)         
         {
             Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
           }
             finally { }
         }
        }
         }
```

Here in this example i am able create a folder(DMS) and sub-folder(SCOSTADL) and i want to create many sub-folders along with Sub-folder(SCOSTADL).please give me  suggestions......

Comment: In this sample app i am able to create folders and sub-folders but i want to create a folder and a sub folder with extra (ex:3folders)folders along with sub-folder

Comment: I don't think we understand what folder structure you want yet. Can you write out what you want, with each folder as a *full* path?

Comment: For example i have created a folder with name ABC and a sub-folder DEF but along with this sub-folder DEF i need more folders like GHI,JKL

Comment: Well, create them one by one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateDirectory` creates all sub-directories in the path as well, so you can do `Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\abc\\def\\ghi");`.

Comment: You forgot the @ sign: `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\abc\def\ghi");`

Comment: i am able to create a folder and sub-folder but i need few folders along with sub folder

Comment: What do you mean? This would create 3 folders: abc, def and ghi, if they don't exist yet...